# check if input file filed is empty jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, file-io

I have a form with a file input and I want to check if it is empty when the form is submitted.

I have this code:

```
$('form#new_comment').submit(function(e) {
   var $this = $(this);
   var $input =  $this.find('input').val();
 if($($input == '')) {
   alert ("you must choose a image");
   return false; 
   e.preventDefault(); 
  }    
});
```

But it always says `you must choose a image`, even when I have chosen an image.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change:

```
if($($input == '')) {
```

To:

```
if($input == '') {
```

Since it is simple variable that holds text, you don't need to use jQuery function over it again.

Comment: The problem was fixed. I had bad id in input file field :D Thank you! Sarfraz

Comment: @hyperrjas: You want to validate all inputs (because you have used `$this.find('input')` which gets all inputs ) or single field ?